# jQuery UI non-visible droppables still accept draggables

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

This is an easily reproduced problem. Check this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MichielCM/XEC9g/

```
<ul id="list1">
    <li>Item 1</li> 
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>

<ul id="list2">
    <li>Hover me over the items</li>
</ul>

<div id="status"></div>
```

List1 exists of drop targets. It's set to a maximum height and its overflow is hidden. List2 has just one draggable item.

```
$("#list1 li").droppable({
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: "pointer",
    over: function(event, ui) {
        $("#status").text(
            "Hovering over: ".concat($(this).text())
        );
    }
});

$("#list2 li").draggable();
```

Now, when dragging the item from list2 over the list of droppables (list1), the 'over' event for each target is activated. This even occurs for the invisible items that are not displayed because of the fixed height. The 'drop' event is triggered for these items as well, so it's in fact possible to drop the item on an invisible target!

Any elegant ways to prevent this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it. Similar behavior is documented in the following bug report. It also contains a workaround calculating elements' actual positions and height. http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8477

I went with a simpler approach, though. By catching the mouseenter and mouseleave events of the container element I could be sure the mouse was actually hovering the list and thus the visible items. Using a class on the list element functioning as a boolean did the rest.

```
$("#list1").live({
    "mouseenter": function(event, ui) {
        $(this).addClass("over");
    },
    "mouseleave":  function(event, ui) {
        $(this).removeClass("over");
    }
});

$("#list1 li").droppable({
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: "pointer",
    over: function(event, ui) {
        if ($(this).closest("ul").hasClass("over") {
            $("#status").text(
                "Hovering over: ".concat($(this).text())
            );
        }
    }
});

$("#list2 li").draggable();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and believe I found a much simpler solution. One can simply pass a function to the `accept` property of the `droppable` function, which returns a boolean saying whether the drop should be accepted.

> http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept

In my case, there were many ways to figure out whether the target was visible with a one-liner.